# Using org-table data for R block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, r

I'd like to be able to plot in an orgbabel chunk these data I have in a org-table:

```
#+NAME:amount
| date             | amount
|------------------+--------|
| <2022-01-30 Sun> |   55.1 | 
| <2022-01-31 Mon> |   54.7 |
| <2022-02-01 Tue> |   54.5 |
| <2022-02-02 Wed> |   55.1 |
| <2022-02-03 Thu> |   54.2 |
| <2022-02-04 Fri> |   54.1 |
| <2022-02-05 Sat> |   53.9 |
| <2022-02-06 Sun> |   54.1 |
```

The idea is to use these data in a R block and plot amount (y axis) as a function of date (x axis):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R 
#+END_SRC
```

How to reference the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the table name to a variable in the R block header:

```
#+NAME:amount
| date             | amount
|------------------+--------|
| <2022-01-30 Sun> |   55.1 | 
| <2022-01-31 Mon> |   54.7 |
| <2022-02-01 Tue> |   54.5 |
| <2022-02-02 Wed> |   55.1 |
| <2022-02-03 Thu> |   54.2 |
| <2022-02-04 Fri> |   54.1 |
| <2022-02-05 Sat> |   53.9 |
| <2022-02-06 Sun> |   54.1 |


#+begin_src R :var tab=amount
  tab[, 2] <-tab[, 2] * 100
  tab
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| <2022-01-30 Sun> | 5510 |
| <2022-01-31 Mon> | 5470 |
| <2022-02-01 Tue> | 5450 |
| <2022-02-02 Wed> | 5510 |
| <2022-02-03 Thu> | 5420 |
| <2022-02-04 Fri> | 5410 |
| <2022-02-05 Sat> | 5390 |
| <2022-02-06 Sun> | 5410 |
```

Note that your orgmode time stamps will be imported as character strings. If you want to use them as dates, you'll need to convert them in R, maybe with `lubridate` or something similar.

### Update

Working with dates in R is a big topic, and off-topic here. Here's a pointer for converting org timestamps to Date objects:

```
#+begin_src R :var tab=amount
  tab[, 1] <- as.Date(tab[, 1], tryFormats = "<%Y-%m-%d")
  plot(tab)
#+end_src
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately my question included the time issue as well. I had a look at lubridate but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: No matter what you do on the Emacs side, you need to process the data in R to get it interpreted properly as dates. There are a lot of ways you could approach this, lubridate is just one option. But I think the details are off-topic for this forum, since they don't have anything to do with Emacs.

Comment: Thanks, I just am searching but couldn't find how to transform orgmode timestamps into R readable dates.

Comment: `as.Date("<2022-01-30 Sun>", tryFormats = "<%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: I'm not sure whether it would ever be significant, but I think org expects `<yyyy-mm-dd>` dates to apply to appointments, scheduled tasks and deadlined tasks. I believe `[yyyy-mm-dd]` (entered using `C-c !`) is the preferred format for "inactive" timestamps. I know nothing about R, so I know nothing about the implications if any this format would have for date conversion in R.

Comment: @PhilHudson the `tryFormats` argument can contain a vector of possible matching patterns.