# Importing org-mode table into R using `read.table()`

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, r

I see [a related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/70646) has already been asked, but it misses my particular use case.

If I have an org-mode table with some data, and I want to import it into an R session, using `read.table`. However, I get an error saying `Error in read.table(test) 'file' must be a character string or connection`:

```
#+TBLNAME: my_tab
|     x | y |
|-------+---|
|   1.2 | d |
| 234.3 | e |
|    32 | f |
|    64 | g |
|-------+---|

#+begin_src R :var test=my_tab :results output :exports none :eval never-export
my_df <- read.table(test)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Error in read.table(test) : 
:   'file' must be a character string or connection
```

But the following does work:

```
#+begin_src R :var test=my_tab :results output :exports none :eval never-export
my_df <- data.frame(test)
#+end_src
```

I'm not quite sure what it is that stops the import from happening in one case but not the other; perhaps it's an issue with type conversion or specifying the correct separator, but no changes I make seem to fix it.

Is there some way to stop the error and just use `read.table()`?

Comment: Are you sure this is an Org mode question? It feels like an R question to me: you need to read the documentation for `read.table` and see what it needs.

Comment: In fact, the `read.table` doc says: "Reads a **file** in table format ...", so you'd have to save the Org table into a file before you can use the file in `read.table`.

Comment: @NickD Well, I asked here as I think it's a reasonable assumption the proportion of org-mode users who work with R is greater than the proportion of R users who use org-mode -- see all the examples on Worg. As for the `read.table` documentation, a little later it says `Alternatively, ‘file’ can be a readable text-mode connection..`, which is what the variable containing the table should be...

Comment: No, it is not: it's literally the data in the table, not a connection to some process that produces the table. You should be able to use the dataframe produced from the in-memory data to save a file that you can then read with `read.table`. But again all of these questions are `R`-specific. This has nothing to do with Org mode.

Comment: Hmm, I see.  I was confused by the fact that in the R session buffer, I see `test <- local({con <- textConnection(     "\"x\" \"y\" \"1.2\" \"d\" \"234.3\" \"e\" \"32\" \"f\"
\"64\" \"g\""   )   res <- utils::read.table( con, header = FALSE, row.names = NULL,  sep  = "\t",  as.is     = TRUE ) close(con)  res})`, but I see that `typeof(test)` is `list`, and what seems to be happening is that a temporary text connection is being created to read the table into the `test` variable. I guess what I wanted to do is to somehow skip the creation of `con`, or directly pipe it into `read.table()`.